# Remind users that have not logged in every 14 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to send an email to users that have not logged in for at least 14 and remind them every 14 days.
So users will get a reminder email 14, 28, 42, 56, 70... days after their last login.
The query will only be executed once a day, but I can change the interval as well.

Currently I use a query like this to get the users that have not logged in in the last 14 days, but I need to extend it to do it every 14 days.

```
SELECT mail FROM users
WHERE   lastLogin >= truncate_to_date(now() - 14 days) 
    AND lastLogin <  truncate_to_date(now() - 14 days + 1 day);
```

- mail is `varchar(255)`
- `lastLogin` is `timestamp`
- `truncate_to_date(timestamp)` -> `timestamp` ( Function that erases the time part from the timestamp (ex: `2016-11-03 14:15:16` -> `2016-11-03 00:00:00`))

I thought of a function like this in sql however I'm not sure how to express it properly in sql.

```
SELECT mail FROM users 
WHERE getDaysSinceEpoch(lastLogin) % 14 = getDaysSinceEpoch(now()) % 14 -- every 14 days
    AND getDaysSinceEpoch(lastLogin) < getDaysSinceEpoch(now()); -- except today
```

Can somebody please give me a clue how i can write the `getDaysSinceEpoch(timestamp)` -> int function?
It would be nice if i could inline this instead of a separate function.

Alternatives I have considered:

- Adding a new field for this: Well thats quite overhead for a rarely used case and the value can always be calculated anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea to use modulo is fine, but the query should be much simpler:

```
select mail 
from users 
where lastlogin < current_date
and (current_date - lastlogin::date) % 14 = 0;
```

Comment: Does not work: `ERROR:  Operator does not exist: interval % integer`

Comment: Ah, then lastlogin  is not a date, but a timestamp. Convert it to date (`lastlogin::date`) and you should be fine. (`date - date = int`; whereas `date - timestamp = interval`.)

Comment: Now it works as expected. Thx. I didn't thought that it would be that simple/short.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect a query such as this:

```
SELECT mail
FROM users
WHERE lastLogin  < current_date AND
      extract(day from (current_date - date_trunc('day', lastLogin) ))::int % 14 = 0;
```

Comment: This misses the condition lastlogin < `current_date` but otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that this solution will work with `timestamp`, but not completely with `timestamptz` (there are some odd cases around DST changes, because the timestamp subtraction uses fix 24 hours as a day, f.ex. `select extract(day from timestamptz '2016-03-27 00:00:00 Europe/London' - timestamptz '2016-03-28 00:00:00 Europe/London')` will yield `0`)